# The Laplace transform of a function $\phi(t)$ can be written as $\hat{\phi}(s) = \cosh (2x\sqrt{s})/(\sqrt{s}\sinh\sqrt{s})$.

Tags: linear-transformations, laplace-transform

> The Laplace transform of a function $\phi(t)$ can be written as $$\hat{\phi}(s) = \cosh (2x\sqrt{s})/(\sqrt{s}\sinh\sqrt{s}).$$ Determine $\phi(t)$ where $x$ is real.

So I know that $$\cosh(at) = \frac{s}{s^2 - a^2}$$ and I know that $$\sinh(at) = \frac{a}{s^2 - a^2}$$ but I'm stuck on how to tet to that point where I can take the inverse Laplace function and determine my answer.

Comment: The inverse Laplace Transform is given by the Bromwich integral$$\begin{align}
\phi(t;x)&=\frac1{2\pi i }\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}\frac{\cosh(2x\sqrt s)}{\sqrt s\sinh(\sqrt{s})}e^{st}\,ds\\\\
\end{align}$$Now, the integrand has no branch points since $\frac{\cosh(2xz)}{z\sinh(z)}$ is an even function of $z$.  There is a simple pole at $z=0$ (Are there other poles?).  Is there a way forward to evaluation in closed form?

Comment: so are we then able to say that the inverse laplace is phi(t) = 1/t + 2*SUMMATION( (-1)^n/(t + n^2 *pi^2)

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.

Comment: And feel free to up vote and accept an answer as you see fit. ;-)

Comment: Hi! It's been a while. I hope you're staying safe and healthy during the pandemic. I've reached out to contact you a few times, but am unsure whether you've received the notes? If you would, please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can. And feel free to up vote an answer as you see fit. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The inverse Laplace Transform, $\phi(t)$, is given by the Bromwich integral

$$\begin{align}
\phi(t)&=\frac1{2\pi i }\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}\frac{\cosh(2x\sqrt s)}{\sqrt s\sinh(\sqrt{s})}e^{st}\,ds\\\\
\end{align}$$

The integrand has no branch point singularities since $\frac{\cosh(2xz)}{z\sinh(z)}$ is an even function of $z$.  There are simple poles of the integrand at $s=0$ and $s=-n^2\pi^2$.  Then, we can write for $t>0$

$$\begin{align}
\phi(t)&=\sum_{n=0 }^\infty \text{Res}\left(\frac{\cosh(2x\sqrt s)}{\sqrt s\sinh(\sqrt{s})}e^{st}, s=-n^2\pi^2\right)\\\\
&=\sum_{n=0 }^\infty\lim_{s\to -n^2\pi^2}\left((s+n^2\pi^2)\frac{\cosh(2x\sqrt s)}{\sqrt s\sinh(\sqrt{s})}e^{st}\right)\\\\
&=\sum_{n=0 }^\infty (-1)^n2\cosh(i2xn\pi)e^{-n^2\pi^2t}\\\\
&=2\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \cos(2n\pi x)e^{-n^2\pi^2 t}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Am I wrong or $s=-n^2\pi^2$ would be poles if the denominator contained $\sin\sqrt s$? Here we have $\sinh$ and the unique zero of $\sinh $ is $s=0$

Comment: @Raffaele Note that $\sinh (s)=0$ implies that $e^{2s}=1=e^{i2n\pi}$, $n\in \mathbb{Z}$.   Thus, $s=in\pi$, $n\in \mathbb{Z}$ are the roots of the hyperbolic sine function.  And by squaring, we find that $s^2 =-n^2\pi^2$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The series you arrived to gives an elliptic theta function and $$\phi(t)=\vartheta _3\left(\pi  x,e^{-\pi ^2 t}\right)$$ and there is no way to get the Laplace transform.

Comment: @Raffaele We already know that the Laplace Transform is $\hat \phi(s)=\frac{\cosh(2x\sqrt s)}{\sqrt s \sinh(\sqrt s)}$

Comment: Hi! It's been a while. I hope you're staying safe and healthy during the pandemic. I've reached out to contact you a few times, but am unsure whether you've received the notes? If you would, please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can. And feel free to up vote an answer as you see fit. ;-)

Comment: @MarkViola I'm trying to verify your result but there are some things I do not understand. First, why does the sum run to $-\infty$? Aren't you counting the poles doubly in this way? I think the factor 2 in your final expression is correct though but stems from l'Hopital and the s-derivative of $\sinh{\sqrt{s}}$. Finally, I couldn't verify your result numerically. For instance, at x=0.5 and early times, your sum does not converge. Meanwhile, numerical inversions with the t'Hoog and Talbot algorithms did converge (I can send you my code).

Comment: Note that the summand contains the term $e^{-n^2\pi^2 t}$, which decays to $0$ rapidly for $t\ge t_0>0$.  So the sum should converge quickly.  I've corrected the "double counting" issue.  Thank you for the heads up.